# How to retrieve last two pieces of data from string individually?

Tags: python, string

This code retrieves the last two odds fluctuations for a particular runner in a race. I want to retrieve the last two fluctuations, but I want to retrieve them individually.

`flucs2 = flucs1[-2:]` retrieves the last two fluctuations, but not individually.

`flucs2 = flucs1[-1:]` retrieves the last fluctuation individually

What do I use to retrieve the second last fluctuation individually?

My code:

```
request2 = requests.get('https://www.punters.com.au/api/web/public/Odds/getOddsComparisonCacheable/?allowGet=true&APIKey=65d5a3e79fcd603b3845f0dc7c2437f0&eventId=1051322&betType=FixedWin', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
json2 = request2.json()
data = []
for selection in json2['selections']:
    for fluc in selection['flucs'][0]:
        flucs1 = ast.literal_eval(selection['flucs'])
        flucs2 = flucs1[-2:]
```

Comment: `flucs1[-2:-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using negative indexing will count from the back so `-1` is the last item, `-2` is the second last item etc. You don't need to splice with `:` to get just one item:

```py
>>> list = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
>>> list[-1]
'four'
>>> list[-2]
'three'
```